# Disallow ENV and ENV_JAVA in JRuby

Tags: security, environment-variables, jruby

Is it possible to disallow the use of `ENV` and `ENV_JAVA` in JRuby? I allow user supplied ruby code to run in servers, and I believe allowing them to use `ENV` and `ENV_JAVA` is not a very good idea.

I was able to disallow the use of `System.get/setProperty()` using Java's Security Manager, but I haven't had much success in this case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
class Object
  remove_const :ENV
  remove_const :ENV_JAVA
end
```